# Creating variables from string names

Tags: python, python-2.7

I wanted to know if there's any way of converting a string in python into a variable name and assigning it a default value.
For example suppose I had this loop,

```
for i in range(1,4):
    "User"+str("i")=0
```

It would give me the variables User1, User2 & User3 assigned a default value 0 which I can modify at my discretion.
I know this is possible to do using files but is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it with `eval` but generally I would suggest using a `dict` to store keys (variable names) and associated values:

```
users = {}
for i in range(1,4):
    users["User"+str(i)]=0  
print users
# {'User1': 0, 'User2': 0, 'User3': 0}
```

you can aceess each variable by just accessing the dictionary with the right key:

```
print users['User1']
# 0
```

Answer (score 3):

See `locals` and `globals` as in

```
for i in range(1,4):
    globals()["User"+str(i)] = 0
```

Then `User2` will be in global scope for example

Answer (score 0):

You can use eval(), https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval

```
eval(varname + "=" + value);
```

Comment: `eval` does not work for statement (assignment is a statement) but only for expression.

Comment: you're right.  That works in most scripting language, guess python is different.

A dict the other user mentioned would be the better approach.  If you need to set a member variable, you can use one of those __setattr__() method, but this is dangerous as you can accidentally override other methods.  http://python-reference.readthedocs.org/en/latest/docs/dunderattr/setattr.html